# github ssh keys: do we need just setup authorized_keys instead of id_rsa.pub & id_rsa

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I am able to access the github servers thought ssh.

```
(somenv)bob@somenv:~/.ssh$ ssh -T git@github.com
Enter passphrase for key '/home/bob/.ssh/id_rsa':
Hi Bob! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Here are my files:

```
(somenv)bob@somenv:~$ ls -ltar .ssh
total 24
-rw-r--r-- 1 bob bob  884 Aug 11 14:30 known_hosts
drwx------ 7 bob bob 4096 Aug 11 14:37 ..
-rw------- 1 bob bob  413 Aug 11 14:46 id_rsa.pub
-rw------- 1 bob bob  413 Aug 11 14:47 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 bob bob 1766 Aug 11 14:48 id_rsa
drwx------ 2 bob bob 4096 Aug 11 14:48 .
```

The `authorized_keys` is a copy of `id_rsa.pub`. When I remove the `id_rsa.pub` and `id_rsa`, I cannot authenticate with github. Why not? In other words, how do I get ssh to pass `authorized_keys` to github?

I am trying to deploy my ssh keys through [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mlbright/840655).

Here is my local environment:

```
 (somenv)bob@somenv:~/.ssh$ uname -a
 Linux somenv 3.9.3-x86_64-linode33 #1 SMP Mon May 20 10:22:57 EDT 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need your private key to connect to a remote server, this key is usually named `id_rsa` in the folder `~/.ssh`.

`id_rsa.pub` is the public key component which you supply to github, and `authorized_keys` is the file that has all keys that are allowed to connect to the local machine on this account.

Comment: Thanks - I am trying to understand why [the gist](https://gist.github.com/mlbright/840655) does not work for me. When you say the "local machine", do you mean the machine that I am connecting to github from?

Comment: The file `authorized_keys` is not relevant for your problem. The script you posted can't be used to push your public key to github, as they don't give you shell access.